# LogRendererCore: Warning: Query 'EndOfFrameUpdates' not ready

Tags: unreal-engine5, unreal-blueprint

I have made a game in Unreal Engine 5.2.1 and when I open the game it runs very very laggy. When I open the Unreal Editor, the output log shows this error:
"
LogD3D11RHI: Timed out while waiting for GPU to catch up. (0.5 s) (ErrorCode 00000001) (00000000)

LogD3D11RHI: Timed out while waiting for GPU to catch up. (500 ms)

LogD3D11RHI: Timed out while waiting for GPU to catch up. (0.5 s) (ErrorCode 00000001) (00000000)

LogRendererCore: Warning: Query 'EndOfFrameUpdates' not ready.
" ( it shows like 15 more with these same lines)

I tried to change DirectX 12 to 11 and SM6 to 5 but no luck.

Comment: You will probably have better luck getting an answer on the [Unreal Engine Forums](https://forums.unrealengine.com/categories?tag=unreal-engine) for this type of question. Regardless, make sure you have a system capable of running Unreal Engine (for your specific project) and have the correct drivers installed.